# what is advantage of can rx fifo?

Tags: buffer, message, fifo, can-bus, autosar

I am very interested in AUTOSAR.
I studied CAN message buffer and CAN Rx FIFO.
I understood thart CAN Rx FiFO is collection of message box.
I have a question.
When using the CAN message buffer, it is known that the can message id in the range is processed first through message filtering.
If fifo is a collection of message buffer, I think the only advantage is memory.
Is that all? I'm really curious about the reason to use CAN RX FIFO.

Comment: Is there a specific hardware in your mind? A microcontroller with CAN hardware maybe?

Comment: Yes. It is micro controller with can controller. I'm curious about the advantages of rx fifo in compare with message buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends a lot on the specific CAN controller hardware used. But in general, yes, message id filtering and acceptance masking (if used) is applied before a message ends up in Rx FIFO.

The reason behind having a Rx FIFO is simply to allow your program some time to do other things, while there are incoming messages. When you inspect the FIFO, it is often best to do so until you've read all messages and emptied the FIFO.

The more modern/advanced CAN controllers uses something called "mailboxes" where specific CAN identifiers you are interested in end up in their own dedicated "mailbox" message buffer. The setup then is to have dedicated mailbox for all high priority messages you expect, and leave the RX FIFO for low priority stuff and/or messages that you aren't interested in.

Comment: Keep in mind also the difference between "BasicCAN" filtering and "FullCAN" filtering. FullCAN meaning, a single message is assigned to a Mailbox vs BasicCAN, where the filter allows multiple messages to be received by a mailbox. Mailboxes are usually limited, so that not all messages can be assigned to FullCAN mailboxes. BasicCAN then also means, the final filtering is still done in SW, because the filter mask could still fit to unwanted messages. And new messages could overwrite the already received message if not processed yet in SW.

Comment: @kesselhaus It would seem that you are speaking of some very specific CAN controller. If by "FullCAN" you mean 11 vs 29 bit identifier, then there are plenty of controllers that don't make a distinction as far as mailboxes are concerned.

Comment: No, this was not about Std (11bit) vs Ext (29bit) identifiers. BasicCAN and FullCAN was a terminology (still) even used by ComStack vendors like Vector. FullCAN meaning, the mailbox filter is set to fit a single CAN message ID, where BasicCAN meaning, the mailbox contains a wider CAN-ID filter mask to fit several different messages. see also [can-wiki faq](http://www.can-wiki.info/doku.php?id=can_faq:can_faq_basic_full) ~5th paragraph.

Comment: @kesselhaus Ok so by "FullCAN" they actually mean a controller with mailboxes. As opposed to a simpler one with acceptance mask + filters applied to a rx FIFO.